# Access a JSP map in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I have this JSP that is used to display the list of options in a drop-down menu. For corresponding code looks like this:

```
<a:dropdown name="infoType" nativeId="search-info-dropdown">
 <c:forEach var="option" items="${dropdownOptions}">
  <a:dropdownOption value="${option.key}" selected="${not empty searchBarModel && (searchBarModel.infoType == option.key ? true : false)}">
   .....
  </a:dropdownOption>
 </c:forEach>
</a:dropdown>
```

Now, I am constructing a map in JS that contains **option.key** as key and function calls as value. I need to access all the keys in the **dropdownOptions** map. Something of the sort **dropdownOptions.get(0).getKey()**

How do I access the map contents in such a way in JS?

Thanks!